# Plots dashed when I don't specify them to be dashed?

Tags: plotting, graphics, style, plot-themes

I was plotting a function (F here) with selected values, and just wanted the plot to be solid lines with the selected colors specified with PlotStyle:

```
Plot[{F[11, 2, x*1*^-6], F[18, 22, x*1*^-6], F[54, 77, x*1*^-6], 
F[55, 78, x*1*^-6]}, {x, 0, 10*^3}, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {"Recoil energy (eV)", "Nuclear form factor"}, 
ImageSize -> Medium, 
PlotLegends -> { "23Na", "40Ar", "131 Xe", "133 Cs"}, 
PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue, Orange}, 
LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Courier", FontSize -> 14, Black}]
```

But when I evaluated this, I got the following output with dashed lines instead of solid lines:

[image: Result of evaluating above code.]

This was not a problem until last night, and it occurred every time I plotted something that I wanted to be solid lines. I don't remember doing anything weird either last night.

The only thing that fixed it was copying everything in the notebook and re-evaluating it from scratch in a new one.

If anyone has any idea on what could've caused this to occur, I would be happy to hear about this.

Comment: Does this still happen in a fresh kernel? Otherwise, it could just have been a glitch.

Comment: It disappeared after starting in a fresh kernel. I think Mr.Wizard was correct with his response. I still haven't figured out what changed the PlotTheme setting to Monochrome though...

Comment: Perhaps you were trying things out earlier, and forgot about it. Usually, things you did at `In[5]` would still be remembered at `In[1015]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears something set `$PlotTheme = "Monochrome"`;

```
$PlotTheme = "Monochrome";

Plot[{{x, x^2, Log[x], Exp[x]}}, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Recoil energy (eV)", "Nuclear form factor"}, ImageSize -> Medium, 
 PlotLegends -> {"23Na", "40Ar", "131 Xe", "133 Cs"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue, Orange}, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Courier", FontSize -> 14, Black}]
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like I was too hasty in removing [tag:plot-themes]. (+1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think this was the problem although I have not identified the cause yet of why PlotTheme was switched to monochrome.